# How to perform functional testing from and on Android devices?

Tags: android, functional-testing

Coming from a desktop and web background, I am familiar with tools that allow me to record mouse movements and keystrokes for Functional test.

What for Android apps? Is there any similar tool or tools?  I assume with a device connected to your PC/Mac (emulator), but also simply on the device itself.

For the later, which is what I'm trying to accomplish, I would like to be able to record movements on the screen (just as in the eclipse emulator), i.e. swiping up, down, button on press, on release, etc., and simply have it run on the device itself without being connected to a computer, similar to being able to record a script (functional) and run it over and over, having this installed as an app on the device to allow me to record and run functional scripts as an overlay on top of an app in development?

Like being able to run something like **MonkeyTalk** directly on the device.

Think of being able to record and run Selenium functional scripts directly on and from the device.

Is there an overlay type of idea that would work? I've heard there are some security risks in this.

Looking for a solution please.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose [Espresso Test Recorder](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I see you can record the script on an emulator then deploy the recording onto your device. I'd like to skip the emulator, record and play directly on the device.  Could writing a custom app with their APIs be an option?

Comment: An emulator is not required for the recorder. You can use it completely on a real device.

Comment: Even better. Then I assume you can write an app with it's APIs to customize assertion activities, etc.?  Something like this available for iPhone as well?

Comment: The recorder will generate you java code (espresso tests). If you want, you can customize this code as much as you want (add assertions, change or delete them).

Comment: Oh but can this be used as an overlay on top of other apps or does it need code access to your own APK?  Like if we wanted to test four different versions of our app, just have it installed then run espresso scripts on too of them at will.

Comment: It needs access to your own app. This means that as soon as you execute the tests (from the IDE or command line) the actuall app and tests will be installed at the same time on your device and the tests (technically a second APK with special knowledge and permissions) will execute actions on your app. If it would be possible to controll any app, it would be a huge security treat because apps could read and controll other apps.

Comment: I'm that case, through an emulator, screen-mirroring your phone, could you record functional scripts?  This way the app isn't installed on your phone, it's running on your computer but still executing actions on your phone.  Would that work?

Comment: That makes no sence ... Emulator does not mirror the screen of your phone. It is a virtual phone with its own apps installed. The app and the recorded test have to be running on the device itself (because it is an instrumentation test and not a bare junit test). Please read the linked manual and try it out. This will answer all of your questions :)